# Is there a way to stop VS code from trimming spaces at end of lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working in a project that has wonky whitespaces at the end of lines and don't want to remove them to keep the git diff down.

In `.vscode/settings.json` I have:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": false
}
```

But whitespaces are still trimmed. Is there any setting I can turn on to stop VS code from trimming on save?

Comment: you should disable add on plugins . It might fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling any plugins that might format on save.